# This sculpture is believed __________ in the 15st century in memory of a priest

Tags: passive-voice

> 1.This sculpture is believed ---- in the 15st century in memory of a priest.
>
> A) having made B) to be made C) being made D) to have been made E)
>   having been made

At first when I filled the blank with option D, I thought it sounded better but then I asked myself why I cannot say other options even though if I have to choose an infinitive form like option B and because the date is certain shouldn't I avoid to use present perfect tense.So could you explain why I cannot other options or how to change the sentence so as to use them?

---

> 2. The students denied ---- any instructions by the invigilator as to how to do the listening part in the exam.
>
> A) to be given B) being given C) giving D) having given E) to have
>   been given

The same here. Is it important that the word deny gets the verbs coming after it to take gerund form.if this vital criterion, could you compare options B and D.

Comment: imo, the correct answer to #2 is not among the available choices. The correct phrasing is "The students denied having been given any instructions."

Comment: "The students denied being given any instructions" sounds fine to me; from Google Books: *Zewe denied being given any copies of revised job descriptions*, US National Labor Relations Board, 2012. *[interviewees] denied being trained in the use of weapons and denied being given weapons*, a report. *Frank Dobson has denied being given preferential treatment" (http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/uk_politics/508674.stm). *.. denied being given special treatment* (http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/property/news/8422356/Housing-boss-in-eviction-row-after-young-family-told-to-leave-against-wishes.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.

Shouldn't you avoid using the present perfect tense?   Yes, you should, and yes, you did.  The "is believed" licenses an infinitive phrase as its direct object.   The infinitive is a non-finite form -- it has no tense.

The available options include two infinitives:  B) to be made, and D) to have been made.   Although these forms have no tense, they do have voice and aspect.   Option B) employs the passive voice and the indefinite aspect.   Option D) employs the passive voice and the perfect aspect.

It seems likely that the sculpture exists.   It is complete, or at least it was completed.   For this reason, it is sensible to use the perfect aspect.

2.

Gerunds are also non-finite forms that have an aspect.   Specifically, they employ the continuous aspect.

Only three options are gerunds:   B) being given, C) giving, and D) having given.   B) is a passive voice gerund phrase.   C) and D) employ the active voice.   D) also employs the perfect aspect.

We can consider these gerunds to have an implied subject.   That is to say, the subject of the sentence also governs the gerund.   In the active voice, the subject is the semantic agent or actor.   In the passive, the subject is the semantic patient, beneficiary or recipient.

Since the agent is provided by the prepositional phrase "by the invigilator", the subject needs to be the recipient, and only a passive voice construction makes sense.   Among the provided options, only B) is a passive voice gerund construction.

Answer (score 1):

No. 1 to have been made

You cannot say

> *The sculpture has been made in the 15th century.

Because, you can't usually mention a past time when using the present perfect.

But you can say

> The sculpture is believed/thought to have been made in the 15th century...

As far as No 2, the invigilator is the one who gives the instructions, as you can see by the **by**, which states the agent. And the students who receive the instructions

Answer (score 0):

For 1, they would make totally different sentences. Eg A) **Having made** the sculpture, [Mr Sculptor] delivered it to the church to be installed. B) This sculpture is believed **to be made** of local marble. C) In the 15th century, similar sculptures were **being made** all across the region. D is correct. E) **Having been made** of good quality marble, the sculpture is still in good condition today. None of them bar D can be made to fit the sentence whilst preserving its meaning.

In 2, the first reason D is wrong and B is right is simply because the invigilator gives exam instructions and the students don't. But the grammar reason is that "denied having given *by*" isn't correct. It would have to be "denied having given *to*". If the question were freeform I would have answered "having being given" but that might be BrE-specific.